# Completion of a partial drawing of NFA

Tags: computer-science, automata

To the automaton in the following partial diagram I am required to add inputs, transitions, and accepting states so that the automaton gets all the numbers starting with the digit 1 and after that can be any number of zeros, and also all those numbers plus the digits 11 and again any number of zeros (This is the wording of the instructions). It is also required not to remove states from the drawing and that the automaton be non-deterministic.

[The partial diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N4KV.png)

According to these instructions I added to the drawing inputs, transitions, and one accepting state (in q3).

[The diagram with my additions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3PRh.png)

What I have learned is that a non-deterministic automaton requires a transition that has one input goes to two states and the fact that there is a choice for a given input makes it non-deterministic.
But where can I add another transition for one of the inputs to make it an NFA?
(I also do not understand why q4 is needed).Thanks

Comment: I really doubt this is the wording of the instructions. It is really obscure.

Comment: It's an NFA because all of the inputs were not specified. If you fill in the missing arcs you get a DFA which is still an NFA. You don't need epsilon transitions to have an NFA.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin
The wording would have seemed strange to me too, which is why I mentioned that it was the wording of the instructions. In the rest of the exercises I received, the wording is indeed much clearer.

Comment: Well, then the first step is to translate the instructions by giving a regular expression of the language that the automaton is supposed to accept. Then it will be possible to help you if needed.